# How do I improve this code for hyperbolic numbers so to allow equation-solving?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, matrix

I have the following code, which allows evaluating expressions with split-complex unity `J`:

```
Unprotect[Power]; Power[0, 0] = 1; Protect[Power];
$Pre = If[FreeQ[#, J], #, Module[{tmp},
          
     tmp = Evaluate[
        MatrixFunction[Function[J, #], {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]] // 
       FullSimplify;
           tmp /. {{a_, b_}, {b_, a_}} -> a + J b]] &;
```

After first run it allows evaluating functions of `J` just as if it was an embedded constant. But trying to slove equations with it fails, and returns useless output. Can this code be modified so that `Solve` and `Reduce` also would work?

An example of possible equations:

`Solve[(a+b J)^2==1,{a,b}]`

`Solve[(a+b J)^2 == (a + b J), {a, b}]`

`Solve[(a+b J)^2==J,{a,b}]`

`Solve[(a+b J)^(a+b J)==1,{a,b}]`

Comment: Why not simply define `J^2==1` ? (after unprotecting `Power`)

Comment: @DanielHuber does not work for me, makes things worse, even expressions after this are not evaluated.

Comment: I have MMA 12.3. what version do you have? For your first equation I get the result: : `{{b -> -Sqrt[J] - a J}, {b -> Sqrt[J] - a J}}`

Comment: @DanielHuber I get nonsciential ```MatrixFunction[
 Function[J, {{b -> -Sqrt[J] - a J}, {b -> Sqrt[J] - a J}}], J]``` Is it what you get as well?

Comment: @DanielHuber and for ```Solve[(a+b J)^2==1,{a,b}]``` I do not get anything.

Comment: Note, I did not use your function, I simply set J^2=1 and got he above result. And try  a new kernel in case you have old definitions.

Comment: @DanielHuber in that case you cannot evaluate expressions of split-complex numbers, such as ```Log[J]```, etc. That's why I need improvement of my code. I need solving logarithmic equations, exponential equations, trigonometric equations, etc.

Comment: As J^2=1 it follows 2 Ln[J]= 0. Therefore Ln[J]=0.

Comment: @DanielHuber of course, not. This equality does not work even for -1. $\log j=\frac{i \pi }{2}-\frac{i j \pi }{2}$ You can see it using my code.

Comment: You are right. But what about defining Ln[J]= n Pi I , where n is an Integer?

Comment: @DanielHuber look, in split-complex numbers there is a formula: $f(a+bj)=\frac{1}{2} (f(a-b)+f(a+b))+\frac{j}{2} (f(a+b)-f(a-b))$, take $f(z)=\ln z, a=0,b=1$ and you will see the result. $i \pi$ is logarithm of $-1$. $e^{i\pi}=-1$.

Comment: Are the $a$ and $b$ in your equations supposed to be real, or split-complex numbers themselves?

Comment: @user3257842 real.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is:

```
JEq[a_] := (a /. {J -> 1}) &&   (a /. {J -> -1})
JEv[a_] := Module[{c, d}, (c + J d) /. 
   Solve[JEq[a == c + J d], {c, d}][[1]]]
```

Here `JEq` turns any split-complex (hyperbolic) equation into a conjunction of real equations, allowing it to be solved. And `JEv` evaluates a split-complex expression.

Example for `JEq`:

```
In[2]:= JEq[(a + b J)^2 == 1]
Out[2]= (a + b)^2 == 1 && (a - b)^2 == 1

In[3]:= Solve[JEq[(a + b J)^2 == 1], {a, b}]
Out[3]= {{a -> -1, b -> 0}, {a -> 0, b -> -1}, {a -> 0, b -> 1}, {a -> 1, b -> 0}}
```

Example for `JEv`:

```
In[4]:= JEv[1/(a + J*b)]
Out[4]= a/((a - b) (a + b)) - (b J)/((a - b) (a + b))
```

They will work correctly for most expressions or equations, including exponential ones:

```
In[5]:= JEv[2^(1 + 2 J)]
Out[5]= 17/4 + (15 J)/4
```

Edit: this piece of code should remove the need to wrap split-complex equations in `JEq`, by doing the transformation automatically.

```
Unprotect[Equal];
Equal[a_, b_] := 
 Activate[JEq[Inactive[Equal][a, b]]] /; 
  Not[FreeQ[a, J] && FreeQ[b, J]]
Protect[Equal];
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to do powering with matrices as powers. The first three can be handled as below.

```
jmat = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
iden2 = IdentityMatrix[2];
mat = a*iden2 + b jmat;
lpolys1 = Flatten[mat . mat - iden2];
lpolys2 = Flatten[mat . mat - mat];
lpolys3 = Flatten[mat . mat - jmat];

In[405]:= Solve[lpolys1 == 0, {a, b}]
Solve[lpolys2 == 0, {a, b}]
Solve[lpolys3 == 0, {a, b}]

(* Out[405]= {{a -> 0, b -> -1}, {a -> 0, b -> 1},
 {a -> -1, b -> 0}, {a -> 1, b -> 0}} *)

(* Out[406]= {{a -> 0, b -> 0}, {a -> 1/2, b -> -(1/2)},
{a -> 1/2, b -> 1/2}, {a -> 1, b -> 0}} *)

(* Out[407]= {{a -> -((-1)^(1/4)/Sqrt[2]), 
  b -> (-1)^(3/4)/Sqrt[2]}, {a -> (-1)^(1/4)/Sqrt[2], 
  b -> -((-1)^(3/4)/Sqrt[2])}, {a -> -((-1)^(3/4)/Sqrt[2]), 
  b -> (-1)^(1/4)/Sqrt[2]}, {a -> (-1)^(3/4)/Sqrt[2], 
  b -> -((-1)^(1/4)/Sqrt[2])}} *)
```

Comment: This removes the possibility of working with arbitrary expressions of J. This is not what I wanted to do.

Comment: And yet...it answers the question you actually asked. There's a moral in this, somewhere.

Comment: I asked how to modify the code so that it would permit solve and reduce to work with split-complex numbers just like with any other expressions.

Comment: Ah. I thought the objective was to solve for `{a,b}`. Offhand I do not see a way to go about this that does not use the standard 2x2 matrix representation for `J`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

Adding this line to the front of a notebook simply allows to treat tessarines as any other number, including the equations:

```
$Pre = (# /. J -> {-1, 1}) /. {x_, y_} -> (x + y)/2 + (J (y - x))/2 &;
```

Like this:

```
In:=Log[J]

Out:=(I Pi)/2 - (I Pi J)/2
```